# How to load third party class to my cakephp project?

Tags: php, cakephp, mpdf

Im trying to add third party class (mPDF) to my project. What i am doing wrong with this ? I put all of files to `app/Vendor/mPDF` directory and make that

```
        App::import('Vendor', 'mPDF', array('file' => 'mPDF'.DS.'mpdf.php'));

        $this->mpdf = new $this->mPDF1();
        $html = '<font> TEST</font>';

        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $this->mpdf->Output();
```

EDIT:
Now code is looking like this:

```
public function grafikRehabilitant(){
    $this->autoRender=false;
    $this->layout='pusty';
    App::import('Vendor', 'mPDF', array('file' => 'mPDF'.DS.'mpdf.php'));

    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $html = '<font> TEST</font>';

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();

}
```

And here is error :

> Notice (8): Undefined index: BODY [APP\Vendor\mPDF\classes\cssmgr.php,
>   line 966]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined index: BODY>>ID>>
>   [APP\Vendor\mPDF\classes\cssmgr.php, line 1011]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined offset: -1 [APP\Vendor\mPDF\classes\cssmgr.php,
>   line 1150]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined index: outline-s [APP\Vendor\mPDF\mpdf.php, line
>   3892]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC
>   [APP\Vendor\mPDF\mpdf.php, line 27505]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC
>   [APP\Vendor\mPDF\mpdf.php, line 27608]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC
>   [APP\Vendor\mPDF\mpdf.php, line 9158]
>
> Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
>   by (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php:801)
>   [APP\Vendor\mPDF\mpdf.php, line 7447]
>
> Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
>   by (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php:801)
>   [APP\Vendor\mPDF\mpdf.php, line 1736]
>
> mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send
>   PDF file

**FULL WORKING CODE**

```
            $this->autoRender=false;
            $this->layout='pusty';
            error_reporting(0);
            App::import('Vendor', 'mPDF', array('file' => 'mPDF'.DS.'mpdf.php'));

            $mpdf = new mPDF();
            $html = '<font> TEST</font>';

            $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
            $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: please have a look at this link...
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/segy/2012/01/19/mpdf_component_for_generating_pdf_files_from_html... a demo code link is also provided there..

Comment: Double check your directory. There is `vendors` and `app/Vendor`. The path you mention in your answer matches neither of these. Or is it just a typo?

Comment: @lethal-guitar - i put this file to app/Vendor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two errors you get are caused by the previous notices. By looking at the code linked by  Nishant Solanki, I see that they are supressing notices before the import, like this:

```
// mPDF class has many notices - suppress them
error_reporting(0);

// mPDF import follows
```

Without the notices, the `headers already sent` won't happen.

Comment: This digit 1 now is not exist. I just only change name of class to see other errors.

Comment: you are fu%$ng awesome !!

Comment: @przeqpiciel Thank you :D I faced a similar problem when implementing PowerPoint export in a CakePHP app some time ago